# Vox Populi badge, but no Suffrage badge?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, voting-badges

Today I received my Vox Populi badge on the skeptics site, but I had no previous Suffrage badge and didn't receive one.

Aren't the requirements for Vox Populi stricter than the Suffrage badge, so shouldn't both be awarded?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because some badges are more expensive to award than others, our scheduled task will only run them a certain percentage of the time.

In this case, "Vox Populi" ran before "Suffrage."

Check your profile; you should have all your stinkin' badges now :)

Comment: Wouldn't the Vox Populi badge be more expensive to award? Given that anyone who gaining Vox Populi could have also gained another award, Suffrage. Perhaps I have no idea what your vague terms mean, and should for some reason now insult the person asking why their duly earned badge was not registered in due time.

Comment: The badge engine is pretty simplistic. Each badge is given a "1 out of N" chance to run based on how expensive its query is, e.g. both Vox Populi and Suffrage have a 1 out of 5 chance of running. However, because there is no concept of run hierarchy, Vox can run before Suffrage, even though Suffrage would be earned before Vox.