# Different number of badges in the header and badges tab

Tags: support, badges

Sometime last week I received a Suffrage and Vox Populi badges on stackoverflow. But the bronze badge counter in my account page and my user card increased by 1, not 2. And now I have a different number of badges in my user card/page header(22 bronze badges) and in the badges tab of my account(23 badges). Here is the screenshot of what it looks like.

Account summary page:

[image: account summary page]

Header:

[image: header]

Badges tab:

[image: badges tab]

I looked at different questions on meta stack, i.e. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/vox-populi-badge-but-no-suffrage-badge), but they don't seem to explain my situation. And it's been like this for several days now, I got awarded several new badges, but the counter is still 1 off. Is this a bug, or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: The one is the count of distinct badges. So if you have earned a couple of badges more than once, the count of distinct badges doesn't increase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 3 **silver** badges and 22 **bronze** badges, for a total of 25 badges. The badges summary page says you have 23 **different** badges, meaning that two of them have been repeated.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. I misunderstood how the counting works. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes(it won't let me accept it right now)